# How do I determine if a class is a Grails domain object?

Tags: grails, groovy, dns

For an arbitrary object what is the easiest way to determine if the type of the object is a Grails domain class?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the GrailsApplication for that. Add a dependency injection to your controller or service:

```
def grailsApplication
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
def foo = ...
if (grailsApplication.isDomainClass(foo.getClass()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Where does this method come from? I can't seem to find it in the Javadoc: http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html

Comment: It's a dynamic method, so it's not in the Javadoc. All artifacts work this way, e.g. isServiceClass works too. And if a plugin adds an artifact, it would work too, e.g. the Quartz plugin - isTaskClass works if you have Quartz installed. These methods are described here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/12.%20Plug-ins.html#12.5%20Evaluating%20Conventions

Answer (score 2):

Found the following snippet at https://svn.intuitive-collaboration.com/RiskAnalytics/trunk/riskanalytics-grails/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/GrailsDataBinder.java

```
DomainClassArtefactHandler.isDomainClass(clazz)
```

The javadoc is here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/DomainClassArtefactHandler.html#isDomainClass(java.lang.Class)